# get text from listview and send to context menu

Tags: android, contextmenu

so i have listview that load data from mysql..
it loads ID (visibility:gone), name, price,..per list
i want it when i long click and context menu show and i click item in or item out it will get item's ID and send to next activity..but mine only get 1st ID of listview..please help me

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();
    registerForContextMenu(lv);

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Barang Masuk/Keluar");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Masuk");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Keluar");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getTitle() == "Masuk") {
         String pid = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
         .toString();

        // Starting new intent
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                galian_barang_masuk.class);
        // sending pid to next activity
        in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
        startActivityForResult(in, 100);

    } else if (item.getTitle() == "Keluar") {
         String pid = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
         .toString();

        // Starting new intent
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                galian_barang_keluar.class);
        // sending pid to next activity
        in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
        startActivityForResult(in, 100);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

so, when i click "pasir" from listview and then context menu show up..
it goes to 1st data on listview "tanah"

http://imageshack.com/a/img835/2201/jrth.jpg

http://imageshack.com/a/img600/7562/ftzl.jpg

if i use direct click on listview onitem click..its working with this code

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
     String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
     .toString();

     Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
     galian_barang_masuk.class);
     in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

     startActivityForResult(in, 100);

     }
     });
```

but when i use context its error..dunno how..

EDIT : i've figure it..i make new textview..and i load ID through long click and save it to new textview

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();
            x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x);
            x.setText(pid);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

after that inside onContextItemSelected i change `in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid)` to `in.putExtra(TAG_PID, x.getText().toString());` new textview that i use to collect each listitem ID that i long click..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AdapterContextMenuInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html) to get the selected list item from context menu. For example if you have a List of Strings bound to your ListView, you get the selected item like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
            (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        String listItem = list.get(info.position);
                    //do something with the list item

}
```

Comment: thx for ur answer..but error at list.get(info.position); on list. should list. point to ListView lv = getListView();..?if i use lv.get(info.position); still same..

Answer (score 0):

findViewById(R.id.pid) , each of the row in the list will have a view with the same id. So the result can be random (not sure whether it will always pick the first match or not). In these cases you can try using a custom adapter which can set the required value as tag for the view.
i.e while rendering the list row, use setTag method to set required value for the textview and then later retrieve it using getTag.

Comment: nope..its not the same id..it load from mysql each item have different ID it load to textview each list item..when i use onCLick its work on different listitem when open next edit item (which listitem that i click)..but its not working when i try to move to context menu..help

this is my database..like u can see its different pid(ID)
http://imageshack.com/a/img545/5865/07lx.jpg

Comment: @AmatirtaAngelo i am not referring to your mysql data. In the first case you are doing findViewById(R.id.pid), so as per my assumption there are multiple views with the same id (R.id.pid is not a dynamic value).
Its working in listitem click because you are searching within the context of that particular row i.e view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).
Hope this helps.